# EF-Core How to stop nested objects using Include

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

When using Include UserRole its load all child objects, Why SQL use inner join not left join? 
data of departments are no problem but only UserRole I want stop load [users] under [UserRole]

Image: [data here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wivPS.jpg)

```
public partial class User_Master
{   
    public virtual UserRole UserRole { get; set; }
}

public partial class UserRole
{
    public virtual ICollection<User_Master> Users { get; set; };
}
```

/

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User_Master>(e => {
                    e.HasOne(p => p.UserRole).WithMany(b => b.Users).HasForeignKey(k => k.user_role_id).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
                    e.HasOne(p => p.Department).WithMany(b => b.Users).HasForeignKey(k => k.department_code).IsRequired(false).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
                });
```

/

```
_db.User_Master.Include(x => x.UserRole).Include(x => x.Department).OrderBy(m => m.name).AsNoTracking();
```

Comment: Well, SQL statements are Instructed by your code. When you include, you're telling EF to also pass along the included object. so since you .Include(x => x.UserRole) it will pass it through

Comment: How to fix it? I don't need to load data in UserRole.users it should be null

Comment: I'm afraid you can't, because anytime you include navigation property, the inverse navigation property is automatically included. This is "by design", so there is nothing you can do. If that's important, consider creating separate classes (a.k.a. DTOs, ViewModels) and use projection queries (`Select`) to populate them. Packages like AutoMapper would greatly help with that, as well as mapping them back to entities when you need to perform add/update/delete actions.